# How to add an element to a list of a data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have defined two data types: Point and Curve. Point has two doubles for its coordinates and a Curve has a starting Point and a list of Points representing the rest of the Curve. I need to make a function that creates this Curve given a starting Point and a list of Points but I can't quite understand how am I supposed to add an element to the list of Points inside the Curve.
Here is my code:

```
data Point = Point Double Double deriving (Eq, Show)
point :: (Double, Double) -> Point
point (x, y) = Point x y

data Curve = Curve Point [Point] deriving (Eq, Show)

curve :: Point -> [Point] -> Curve
curve x [] = Curve x []
curve x [y] = Curve x [y]
curve x (y:ys) = curve x (y:ys)
```

I am pretty sure my recursion in the end is wrong. So could you give me maybe some guidelines on how to add a point in the list?

thanks

Comment: Why not just `curve x ys = Curve x ys`? (Or a better question: Why do you want `curve` at all, when all you seem to be looking for is precisely the constructor `Curve`?)

Comment: I don't know D:
I am utterly confused with functional programming. I read an online book but I still fail to grasp some fundamental concepts :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> myCurve = Curve (Point 2 2) [Point 3 3, Point 4 4, Point 5 5]
> ```

Wait, what, you say? Indeed, `Curve` is already that function you want. It is both a type constructor (the left-hand-side in the data definition) and a value constructor (the right hand side.)

If you probe `Curve` with ghci, you will find...

> ```
> Prelude> :t Curve
> Curve :: Point -> [Point] -> Curve
> ```

The same goes for `Point`. In other words, the entirety of your code looks like this:

> ```
> data Point = Point Double Double deriving (Eq, Show)
> data Curve = Point [Point]       deriving (Eq, Show)
> ```

EDIT: An ultra-small primer on value constructors.

When you create a new datatype, you automatically create a value constructor, which is a function that creates a value of the new type. It's not entirely clear in your example because the type and value constructors have the same name, which is permissible in Haskell because one lives in the type level and the other in the value level. Let's try and make it a bit more obvious:

```
data MyIntType = MakeIntType Int
```

Now, `MakeIntType` is a function that takes one argument, an `Int`, and creates a value of type `MyIntType`. Let's check that in ghci:

```
Prelude> :t MakeIntType
MakeIntType :: Int -> MyIntType
```

Now, we could write an identical function, like you're proposing:

```
makeIntType :: Int -> MyIntType
makeIntType x = MakeIntType x
```

or, dropping the explicit points (arguments):

```
makeIntType = MakeIntType
```

Both equation shows that we've duplicated work. There is no functional difference between makeIntType and MakeIntType. They are completely equivalent, and since you will always get the value constructor function "for free," makeIntType is a completely superfluous alias for something that's already there.

I hope that clears things up a bit.

Edit 2: Creating a new modified `Curve` based on an existing one

```
addPointToStartOfCurve p (Curve p' ps) = Curve p (p':ps)
```

Here, we create a new Curve from an existing one by pushing the first element of the existing Curve onto the list of points and adding a new starting point. Another variant would add a point to the end of an existing Curve.

```
addPointToEndOfCurve p (Curve p' ps) = Curve p' (ps ++ [p])
```

Note that because of immutability, the original curves aren't altered, we're just producing new values.

Comment: But don't I need the functions to create the Points and the Curves? I mean if I want to create a Point given two number shouldn't I pass them through a function that will "transform" that pair in a Point?

Comment: `Point` and `Curve` are those functions. In fact, your function `point` taking a tuple `(Double, Double)` as its only argument, does exactly the same as the function `Point`, except it takes two arguments of type `Double`.

Comment: I guess the fact that value-constructors are written upper-case and with the same name as the type might be a bit confusing to you here - see you could write `data Curve = MkCure Point [Point] ...` and then `MkCurve` would be your value constructor (some people still use this kind of naming) - so you would `MkCurve startPoint poins` to create a curve - does this help?

Comment: @Sarah I need to have these two functions though. So do you know what I can do with the function curve so that I can add elements to the list of the Curve?

Comment: @sokras Sure, though I don't see why you "need" them when you already have them. But here is your wanted function: `curve = Curve`. :)

Comment: @sokras if you mean "add" after you created the curve then you are out of luck - you don't - you create a new curve instead

Comment: @CarstenKönig but isn't there a way to access the list inside the Curve so that I can add a Point to it? Or maybe create the list first and populate it with Points and then create the Curve based on this list

Comment: @sokras: Are you talking about mutating an existing Curve? You can't. Haskell values are immutable.

Comment: @Sarah Yeah I know that they are immutable. But can't I recursively create the list based on the one that I give as a parameter and when the iterated list is empty then create the Curve?

Comment: @sokras> I've added yet another edit. I'm still not sure if I understand you correctly, though.

Comment: @Sarah So from what I understand from your edit is that I try to do the same thing twice

Comment: @sokras: Well yes, but that first edit was from when I thought you were simply trying to make another function like `point` that simply creates a curve from scratch.

Comment: @Sarah yes that is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: @sokras: If something is still unclear, I can try to elaborate, but I think I've covered all options now. :-)

Comment: @Sarah  I want to make a recursion on the list of Points that the function "curve" is given so I can pass them to the list of Points of the Curve. But I want to create the Curve once I have passed through all the Points of the parameter list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60746/discussion-between-sarah-and-sokras).